# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? 5

Tags: приложение

Напомню, что в СССР контроль над безопасностью опасных производственных объектов осуществлялся государственным надзорным органом — Госгортехнадзором — в рамках его полномочий, а также в рамках ведомственного надзора.

Comment: По-моему, всё правильно. А что Вас смущает?

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь проблема с предлогом: "над" объектами, но "за" безопасностью.

Comment: Alenka, по-моему, что-то тут не то! Из приведённого Вами текста следует, что **контроль "в рамках ведомственного надзора" осуществлялся  Госгортехнадзором**.

Автор текста действительно именно это хотел сказать?

Comment: Да, насчет предлога - согласна. Пропустила. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что в предложении надо дополнить концовку, к примеру: "Напомню, что в СССР контроль  за безопасностью опасных производственных объектов осуществлялся **государственным** надзорным органом — Госгортехнадзором — в рамках его полномочий, а также **различными службами и отделами охраны труда** в рамках **ведомственного** надзора".